# Can I have an dynamic array of IDirect3DVertexBuffer9?

Tags: delphi, directx

I am working with Delphi and DirectX. I want an dynamic array of IDirect3DVertexBuffer9. Is it possible? If yes then how?

I have written a code for it. But, it seems to be problematic. My code is shown below -

```
totalBuffer := 4;
SetLength(g_pVB,totalBuffer);
for cnt := 0 to totalBuffer - 1 do begin
      if FAILED(g_pd3dDevice.CreateVertexBuffer(1 * SizeOf(TD3DXVector3),
                                                0, D3DFVF_XYZ,
                                                D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, g_pVB[cnt], nil)) then begin
         Result := E_FAIL;
         Exit;
      end;
      if FAILED(g_pVB[cnt].Lock(0, 0, Pointer(pVert[cnt]), 0)) then begin
         Result := E_FAIL;
         Exit;
      end;
      pVert[cnt] := 0;
end;
```

here, the problem I am facing is that, once it enter in for loop it continues and not exit the loop when `cnt` value is 4. And if I write static value 3 in for loop instead of totalBuffer it will exit the loop when value is 4.

Comment: You mean if you use `for cnt := 0 to 3` it works as intended, but in the current code sample it doesn't?

Comment: @Himadri - Put a 'breakpoint' on the `for` and a 'watch' on `totalBuffer`, and begin tracing to see when 'totalBuffer' changes from 4 to sth. else; Some local variable (assuming totalBuffer is local) seems to be overwriting it.

Comment: So, you have actually *witnessed* this code execute *more than* four times? What happens in the fifth iteration?

Comment: @sertac @Rob Nothing wrong happened in 5th iteration. But after some loop it shows garbage value for `totalBuffer`. And if I press F9 then it will show me error of `Access Violation`. I at least know about breakpoint and watch using that only I came to know that it is executing more than 4 times.

Comment: Oh, I got it working correct today. May be it was the problem with my Delphi tool. Anyways, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find samples [here](http://www.clootie.ru/delphi/download_dx90.html#Direct3D). At **Cull sample** they used "array of IDirect3DVertexBuffer".